# Why I couldn't commit a folder which I deleted accidentally in master in git?

Tags: git

I accidentally deleted my folder named 'log' in the master. When I recreate that folder in my local and try to push that to master but git says 'everything is upto date' 
Why git is not allowing me to push the folder which I accidentally deleted in the master?

```
Rathas-MacBook-Pro:Dataloader ratha$ git add log/
Rathas-MacBook-Pro:Dataloader ratha$ git commit -m "log folder"
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
Rathas-MacBook-Pro:Dataloader ratha$ git push
Everything up-to-date
```

I tried git pull several times ten try to recraete a 'log' folder and trying to push that to master.But not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"folder" is not tracked by git, only "file" is tracked. If you want to "commit" a folder, you need to put some file into it first. A convention to do that, is to put an empty file named `.gitkeep` in it, then commit it.

You can use `git status` to see what git tells you about your working directory. If you just create bunch of empty folders, then `git status`. You'll see that, git can't even notice them exisit. Only until you put real files in folders, they become visible to git.

Also check if any glob that matches the "log/" folder appears in the `.gitignore` config file, this can be the cause too.

Comment: i tried no success.because of same name i use again?

Comment: @Ratha, what exactly have you tried? Also check if the log/ folder appears in the `.gitignore` config file, this can be the cause too.

Comment: Thanks that is the issue. I added *.log file in it and tried to push back but it didnt work because of  .gitignore file. Again created a file .gitkeep and able to commit my log folder. Thanks a lot